# com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64.xpc

Tags: macos, safari, plugins

Had the following appear when attempting to login to an account.  What does it mean & should I approve?
 com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64.xpc wants to use your confidential information stored in "v4.services.acrobat.com" in your ketchain.
To allow this, enter the "login" keychain password.

Always Allow            Deny          Allow

Answer (score 1):

Unless you trust that you understand what that app wants from the keychain (which could be a harmless - secure token generated to not track you but store a session or could be the password to a very important service and not harmless t all) - the best option is to deny the request and see what breaks.

Unless you have a good reason to allow access to keys, you shouldn't.